# Retrieving names of all open pdf files, via python, vbscript or a Windows cmd line

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, vbscript, process

This question is similar to a question posed on [StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5601/retrieving-names-of-all-open-pdf-files-in-evince-or-otherwise), and I copied some of the text in it.

I constantly have many PDF files open in my Win 10 computers.

I sometimes want to make a list of all my open PDF files, so I could re-open the same group of documents at a later time.

This mostly happens when I need to reboot and want to have the same set of documents re-opened, but sometimes I just want to keep a list of open documents for later.

Is there a way to get the names of all open pdf files, using vbscript or python, or some windows command line?  Once I learn how to do this, I'll make similar routines to get a list of python files I'm editing, vbs files I'm editing, txt files, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you may find the following helpful for this:

- [Windows Sysinternals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals)
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/

One of the utilities it includes is [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).  You can use a filter to see which `.pdf` files processes are using.

Comment: Dear jq170727, Thank you for the tip.  But I can't figure out how to use Process Monitor to see a list of .pdf files that processes are using.  I apologize for my ignorance.  Could I impose on you to give me some guidance?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at a windows machine at the moment but a quick search turned up this thread on ServerFault which has more details https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows